# Which is good IL editor

Tags: .net, reflection, bytecode, il, disassembly

I am looking for some good free IL editor which also allows editing bytecode. There were options earlier like "Reflexil" with Reflector but now they are paid or discontinued.

I am using ILSpy at moment for reflection. There are also tools like Telerik Decompile etc. But they all land on same thing "decompile it" + "change code" + "compile again".

What I am looking is to directly edit the assembly at IL or Byte level without recompiling code again (like some Hex editor).

Comment: I have seen such tools in one of seminars where presenter was editing signed assembly without recompiling it. So such tools are possible and also available.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at http://reflexil.net/, it may suit your needs.

Comment: That's already mentioned in the question. The problem is that it depends in Reflector, which is not free anymore. Though it seems it also supports JustDecompile, which could work.

Comment: Reflexil gives illusion that you are doing live editing but actually both of them still follow same flow "decompile" + "change code" + "recompile".